# One BigDecimal approximately equals another Bigdecimal

Tags: java, precision, bigdecimal

I'm extensively using BigDecimals. I often need to make long calculations and then compare results. Due to these long calculations, the answer is not `1` but rather `0.9999999...`. That's why I can't compare BigDecimals exactly but only to a certain error.

How can I check whether one BigDecimal lies within an epsilon of the other one?

**Remark**: I'm already aware of `answer.subtract(expected).abs().compareTo(epsilon) < 0`. But I have to write it over and over again and I'm looking for an easier way to do it.

Comment: Subtract and compare to your ε, that can't be too hard can it?

Comment: If your calculations aren't precise, why aren't you simply using `double`? Commons Math has a [utility library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/math3/util/Precision.html) for comparing floating points with epsilons.

Comment: what do you need a library for?

Just compare the difference against your epsilon instead of against 0 and you're done.

Comment: @Zinki, I`m aware of this way, I asked for a more elegant way to do it

Comment: If you don't want to write something non-trivial over and over again (which you shouldn't), you should put it in a method and just call that method instead.

Comment: @ТимофейЧудаков I'd argue that doing so would be the *most* elegant way possible. Just put it in a function and call it whenever you need to do your "inexact compare". Importing a library just to do something you can write yourself in a single line definitely is *not* elegant.

Comment: @BoristheSpider in my case, I do need precise calculations.  I'm reverse engineering base price per unit given total sale, quantity and tax rates (per unit & percentages).  The data comes from a 3rd party and no specifications are provided regarding their rounding methods.  So when my total is different by +/-0.01, I want to add or subtract a penny adjustment to ensure the transaction totals still match.  All of my inputs are already BigDecimal.  That being said, I am happy with the answer that Tnmoden is not:  `answer.subtract(expected).abs().compareTo(epsilon) < 0`

Answer (score 5):

```
BigDecimal error = new BigDecimal(1e-5);    

BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal(100);
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(11.2);

if (a.subtract(b).abs().compareTo(error) < 0) {
    // a approximately equals b
}
```

Comment: you need setScale

Comment: @ACV Why do I need a setScale?

Answer (score 0):

Just add your own method in a util class or something:

`if (a.subtract(b).abs().setScale(precision, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN).compareTo(epsilon)>0) {
//they are not different
}`

Comment: You need an abs arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

No Div 0 problems

```
public static boolean almostEqual(BigDecimal a, BigDecimal b) {
    int scale = Math.min(a.scale(), b.scale()) -1;
    return a.setScale(scale, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
               .compareTo(b.setScale(scale, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)) == 0;

}
```

And scale be controlled